# How to make a column of text a new table with one row for every word in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, string, token, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have been trying to use `REPLACE()` in Snowflake to parse text data to make a new dataset but cannot get it to work.

Here's my data:

```
text                           date           ID
I am the one                   2021-01-02     001
harry potter I'd               2021-01-03     002
```

ID is unique to every row.
And I want to change this to the following format within Snowflake

```
word   date         ID
I      2021-01-01   001
am     2021-01-01   001
the    2021-01-01   001
one    2021-01-01   001
harry  2021-01-03   002
potter 2021-01-03   002
I'd    2021-01-03   002
```

Delimiter would be the " ".

Comment: What have you tried?  Why use replace?  Seems like you want to parse each row by ' ' and then insert results into a table for each word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake has [`split_to_table()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) for simple delimiters:

```
select s.value as word, t.date, t.id
from t, lateral
     split_to_table(t.text, ' ') s;
```

Comment: This needs to replace `cross join lateral` with a comma and it will work. It could also replace it with `, lateral` and remove the table() around split_to_table.